# How to play/pause a numpy sound array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, python-sounddevice

So I am making a video player, and am playing sound. The audio is in a numpy array. I have a function that can play/pause the video, but I need something to be able to play/pause the playing of the sound. I am using the module 'sounddevice' to play the audio - the code to play is:

```
sounddevice.play(nparray)
```

Does anyone know how to play/pause the sound. There is an option to stop it, but not pause it.